# How to format a Number in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

1. I want to format a number from 10000 to 10,000.00 is there any way to do it in HTML alone(without controller file) with ng-Model directive?
2. I tried to do it in controller file with a logic and bind it to HTML file. But the controller logic always return a number in "10,000.00" String format. Is there any way to convert "10,000.00"(String) to 10,000.00 (number) and bind it to HTML?...(I want 10,000.00 in type number).

My .html file is something like this

```
div  ng-repeat="array in arrayList"><input type="text" ng-Model="array.amount" </div
```

and my controller file is something like this

```
var arrayList=[{"amount":3000},{"amount":4000},{"amount":5000}];
```

(I apologize for not formatting the html file properly)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

- Use `type="text"` and pattern validation like
  `pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)*"` to limit what the user may enter while
  automatically formatting the value as you do in [your example](http://jsfiddle.net/LCZfd/9/).
- Put an overlay on top of the input field that renders the numbers how
  you want and still allows the user to use the custom `type="number"`
  input controls, like [demonstrated here](http://jsfiddle.net/LCZfd/8/).

The latter solution uses an additional `<label>` tag that contains the current value and is hidden via `CSS` when you focus the input field.

In input type: `"number"` case ngModel type is `number` and in input type:`"text"`, ngModel is `string`

Demo of one use-case: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLwt9xuf/)

Comment: thanks for the help @sidverma. its working and its displaying the value as 3,000. so what changes needs to be done in the directive code to display the value with decimal places as 3,000.00?

Comment: Updated JSFiddle link with working code: https://jsfiddle.net/benlk/4dto9738/  (please extract code as per your requirements) and do upvote so that it will remain on top.